# Google music player is missing some settings options

Tags: google-play-music

In my Nexus 7 in the Google Play Music when I open the app and choose settings from the menu, only  2 things will show:

1. source licenses
2. music version

Where are the other settings?

According to the help menu, you should be able to change things like "automatically cache" or hide "unavailable music"

Comment: Could you post a screenshot please?

Answer (score 1):

You should see them. This is what I see. The first picture if the menu you should be clocking:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar, if not exactly the same, situation.

In my case, in the limited settings menu there was an item labelled "Google Account" which listed multiple accounts. As soon as I chose one of those accounts all of the normal settings menu items appeared.